# Why vlc can't open video file?

Tags: vlc

All video file in my pc can be played by `ffplay`,it is strangle video files can't be played by vlc .
Here are some my vlc configure.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The vlc in my pc will auto exit when to open video file,what is the matter?
Are there some package lost?
How to check it?

```
dpkg -l | grep vlc
ii  browser-plugin-vlc                    2.0.6-4                              amd64        multimedia plugin for web browsers based on VLC
ii  libvlc-dev                            2.2.6-1~deb8u1                       amd64        development files for libvlc
ii  libvlc5                               2.2.6-1~deb8u1                       amd64        multimedia player and streamer library
ii  libvlccore-dev                        2.2.6-1~deb8u1                       amd64        development files for libvlccore
ii  libvlccore8                           2.2.6-1~deb8u1                       amd64        base library for VLC and its modules
ii  vlc                                   2.2.6-1~deb8u1                       amd64        multimedia player and streamer
ii  vlc-data                              2.2.6-1~deb8u1                       all          Common data for VLC
ii  vlc-nox                               2.2.6-1~deb8u1                       amd64        multimedia player and streamer (without X support)
ii  vlc-plugin-notify                     2.2.6-1~deb8u1                       amd64        LibNotify plugin for VLC
ii  vlc-plugin-pulse                      2.2.6-1~deb8u1                       all          transitional dummy package for vlc
ii  vlc-plugin-samba                      2.2.6-1~deb8u1                       amd64        Samba plugin for VLC
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
cvlc test.mp4
VLC media player 2.2.6 Umbrella (revision 2.2.6-0-g1aae78981c)
[00000000025bbb08] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
Segmentation fault
uname -a
Linux MiWiFi 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It is no use to do the following three commands in my pc.

```
sudo /usr/lib/vlc/vlc-cache-gen -f usr/lib/vlc/plugins
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall vlc
```

Smplayer was installed too,both of all can't play video ,when to play video,the error output in smplayer is as below.

MPlayer2 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4+b1 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
Terminal type `unknown' is not defined.

```
Playing /home/debian8/test.mp4.
Cache size set to 2048 KiB

Cache fill:  0.00% (0 bytes)   
Detected file format: QuickTime / MOV (libavformat)


MPlayer interrupted by signal 11 in module: demux_open
ID_SIGNAL=11
- MPlayer crashed by bad usage of CPU/FPU/RAM.
  Recompile MPlayer with --enable-debug and make a 'gdb' backtrace and
  disassembly. Details in DOCS/HTML/en/bugreports_what.html#bugreports_crash.
- MPlayer crashed. This shouldn't happen.
  It can be a bug in the MPlayer code _or_ in your drivers _or_ in your
  gcc version. If you think it's MPlayer's fault, please read
  DOCS/HTML/en/bugreports.html and follow the instructions there. We can't and
  won't help unless you provide this information when reporting a possible bug.
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to help you. Try running VLC from the command line with debug enabled, like this: `VLC_VERBOSE=3 vlc <file>` and post the output.

Comment: [PSA: Please don't post images of text!](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/135943)

Comment: Guss ask me to paste all the output by command VLC_VERBOSE=3 vlc <file>,the content is so long that stackvoerflow warn me not to post it.I had to post in the form of image.

Comment: No waring again ,done.

Comment: This is a segmentation fault, thus a bug in VLC, not a decoding problem (VLC has probably the right codec to display the video).

Comment: ` find $HOME -type f -name '*.xspf'` Rename these files.  Then `vlc --reset-config`  This reset how obvious your vlc config. In audio `outputmodul automatic`or you have no sound.  VLC works here in Jessie.

Comment: find $HOME -type f -name '*.xspf'

Comment: /home/debian8/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf

Answer (score 0):

This question reminds me of some problems that may cause this:

1) is video enabled in vlc at all?

- Tools -> Preferences -> Video tab
- See if Enable video box is checked,if not enable it .
- See if Window decorations is checked, if not check it.
- Set the Output drop-down menu to X11 video output (XCB).

2)In case of downloading video files from torrent, at some points they may show false 100% download, and the file is corrupted and can't be played.
3)If mplayer also can't play the video, check it with other video files.

4)reinstalling vlc sometimes mess things up, I suggest to do :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

5) Tool -> preferences -> Input / Codecs under Codecs, if "Hardware-accelerated decoding" is "disabled" edit it to "Automatic."